# Create Zookeeper Node using zkCli.cmd directly from DOS command line

Tags: cmd, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to use the zkCli.cmd client utility to create a node on a remote zookeeper server from DOS command line directly (i.e. without going into the client utility itself). Is this possible?

I have tried the following:

`D:\apps\zookeeper-3.4.6\bin>zkCli.cmd -server 192.168.1.3:2181 create /test-node test-data`

But it doesn't create any nodes on that zookeeper server.

My final aim is to be create nodes on remote zookeeper server via a .bat file directly for example.

Thanks,
PM.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it on Windows, but on linux you need to echo `create /test-node test-data` and then pipe it as input into `zkCli.sh`.  If you want to then drop out of `zkCli` you have to echo a newline and then `quit` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also having same issue faced on linux, than I found that you can create a znode by provide its data value :

```
create -s /ha/masternode "highavailability"
```